# Bootstrap layout is acting weird on wide monitors

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on a site using Bootstrap and all has gone pretty well until I view some things on wide monitors.

If you check out [this](http://wedgetire.com/services.html) page you can see the different company logos in 3 rows (5 on the first and second, and 2 on the 3rd row).  However, if I expand my browser to be as wide as possible you can see the everything starts to act a bit weird.  Any idea on a simple fix to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that when viewed on a wide monitor, some of the logos pop out of line - 
Try removing the width:170px rule in this part of your css:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px)
.span2 {
width: 170px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you did not specify span class or width on your parent div's

try this: (add "span12" in your class)

```
<div class="row span12" align="center">
        <div class="span2 offset1" id="hankook" align="center"><img src="img/hankook_logo.png" alt="hankook tires"></div>
        <div class="span2" id="geotrac" align="center"><img src="img/geotrac_logo.png" alt="geo trac tires"></div>
        <div class="span2" id="nankang" align="center"><img src="img/nankang_logo.png" alt="nankang tires"></div>
        <div class="span2" id="geostar" align="center"><img src="img/geostar_logo.png" alt="geostar tires"></div>
        <div class="span2" id="milestar" align="center"><img src="img/milestar_logo.png" alt="milestar tires"></div>
    </div>
```